# The entity type Object is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, generics, casting, .net-assembly

I'm creating an object in this way:

```
var assembly = typeof (Cliente).Assembly;
var Tipo = assembly.GetType("Datos." + tipoItem);
var item = Activator.CreateInstance(Tipo);
```

where tipoItem is the name of a class and Datos is the respective namespace.

Cliente is a class in the same namespace.

To store the object in the database I have this generic method:

```
public void AddItem<TItem>(TItem item) where TItem : class
{
    db.Set<TItem>().Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When debugging, the type of the item object is right. If tipoItem is "EmailCliente" then the type of item is Datos.EmailCliente.

The AddItem method receives item as a Datos.EmailCliente object but an exception is thrown:

"The entity type Object is not part of the model for the current context"

When debugging, TItem is of type object instead of Datos.EmailCliente and that's the problem.

I did try to cast item to Tipo using (Tipo), as Tipo, Convert.ChangeType(item, Tipo) but none of those work.

How can I cast item so the AddItem method accepts it.

TIA

**EDIT**:

Based on Andrei's answer this is the code that's working.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(ControlDatos).GetMethod("AddItem");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { Tipo });
generic.Invoke(cd, new object[] { item });
```

where cd is an instance of the class ControlDatos where the AddItem method is defined.

Comment: How are you calling `AddItem<>`?

Comment: @Andrei AddItem(item) I can't use AddItem<Tipo>(item) because Tipo is not recognized but it's redundant as long as the item type is known.

Comment: Do you have non-generic overload for `AddItem`?

Comment: @Andrei That's part of the problem: I can't specify that item is a Tipo object.

Comment: @Andrei No, item could be of any type. It depends of the tipoItem string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `AddItem(item)`, compiler is deriving generic type from the argument and substituting it into method call. Since `item` is of type object (at compile time!) - this is what compiler is using. So really you are calling `AddItem<object>(item)`, which gives you the error.

To resolve this you have to make a call of `AddItem` via reflection:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(ItemRepository).GetMethod("AddItem", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod("Datos." + tipoItem);
generic.Invoke(null, new object[]{item});
```

where `ItemRepository` is the class which defines `AddItem` method.

Comment: Ok, I think it should be method.MakeGenericMethod(new[]{Tipo})

Comment: Let me a minute because the AddItem and its class are static.

Comment: @user1537004, please see edit - first argument of `Invoke` should be `null` for static methods. Also note binding flags.

Comment: Throws me an exception at your second line: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." The funny thing is that the previous version (before the edit) throws me the exception but the item was stored.

Comment: @user1537004, apparently corresponding method is not found. Btw are you sure that this method is static? In OP it is not declared as one.

Comment: The static method is the one which is calling AddItem. AddItem isn't static.

Comment: I'm getting the exception but the item is stored. In the meantime I will handle the exception (the second one). Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: It's working now. I did a mistake. Will post the final version in OP.